# Присваивание атрибутов

Tags: javascript, циклы

Нужен совет. Необходимо функцией передать тегам атрибут `class`, всем одинаковым тегам, но если тег будет `<p>` то ему еще помимо `class` присваиваем `title`. пробовал для начала создать функцию что определяла бы `<p>` и давала ему `title` атрибут. в тестовой версии кода

```
function abc(domFile, loop) {
  if (domFile.nodeName === 'P') {
    return domFile.setAttribute('title', loop);
  } else {
     return domFile.setAttribute('class', loop)
  }
}
```

все работает. а вот когда уже пытаюсь то же самое в своем коде сделать, оно выдает все время else значения, хоть по идее nodeName должно выполняться.

```
function setTitleForElement(domElement, someTitle) {
  if (domElement.nodeName === 'P') {
    for(i=0; i<domElement.length; i++) {
      domElement[i] = domElement[i].setAttribute('title', someTitle)}
      return domElement[i]
    } else {
      for(i=0; i<domElement.length; i++) {
      domElement[i] = domElement[i].setAttribute('class', someTitle)}
      return domElement[i]
   }
}
```

Код работает, значения присваивает, но вот `<p>` выделить среди других тегов не может.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно, что значит "всем одинаковым тегам". Может такой пример на jQuery поможет разобраться.

```js
$("*").addClass('myclass')
$("p").attr('title','My TiTle')
```

```css
.myclass{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a>a</a>
<p>p</p>
<div>div</div>
```